# How to write a spinning odometer in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Hi I would like to create a spinning odometer in QT.
The result should be like this one: 
https://www.shutterstock.com/video/clip-4962995-stock-footage-the-counter-displays-one-million-in-frame.html?src=search/dzZbICGUPQ7RgK0rooSE7A:1:0/gg

Something like the picker in IOS.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are mainly two ways of designing a UI with Qt:

- the "older" method is based on [Qt Widgets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-index.html)
- the current suggested method is via [QML/Quick](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-index.html)

Have a look at the QML [Threading](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-threading-example.html) example, in particular at the [Spinner](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-threading-workerscript-spinner-qml.html) component. Looks much like what you need to achieve.

Comment: Many thanks Massimo, this is exactly what I was looking for. I need to use Qt Widget, so I am trying to port [Spinner](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-threading-workerscript-spinner-qml.html) to QWidget. Spinner is ListView where model is made of Integers and Gradient of transparency overlapped to the ListView. Is there a easy way to create a QlistView where the model is made of integers?

Comment: I guess you can use [QStandardItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html) to provide a simple model to your list. P.S. if my question helped you, please don't forget to vote/accept it, thanks !